# why every time I click my tabs the page is scrolling up a little?

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my jQuery, why every time I click my tabs the page is scrolling up a little?

I think the jQuery has the problem...

```
<script>
//jQuery for the loan calculator tab
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
   });
});
</script>
```

I tried added this snippet to check whether the e.preventDefault() works

```
e.preventDefault();
alert("Was preventDefault() called: " + event.isDefaultPrevented());
```

but the alert box doesn't show up.

Comment: Hello @deLegeb, Can you change that `e.preventDefault()`  from bottom to top. Also if your `<a>` link has `#`, then remove it.

Comment: @saifudeenni I am using the # in <a> links for my tab. Is there any method to link my tab header to it's content?

Comment: you can use `data-toggle` attribute. No need of `<a>` tag. I think this link will help you,  see this :- https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/how-to-add-hidden-toggle-tabs-to-your-website.stml#

Comment: that requires bootstrap, I am not using bootstrap on my page

Comment: I have made a simple solution, see the answer, click function is used, but working is based on data-attribute

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` on li click event does not disable triggering of anchor element. add code below to disable it.

```
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links li a').on('click', function(e) {  
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: are there any errors on console, if not could you add your html code, too?

Comment: i used to have this: <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" class="wide">12 Months</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple solution with data attribute.
see this: **https://codepen.io/nisaifudeen/pen/MPJppr**

**Jquery**

```
$('.wrapper ul li').find(' a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataShow = $(this).parent().find('.heading-c').data('show');
    $('.heading-c[data-show=' + dataShow  + ']').toggleClass('active');

  });
```